# Python parameter validation class in flask

Tags: python, validation, flask

I am writing a Flask app and I want to run validation checks on some of the fields and only if the inserted value in the field is integer or None to proceed with the POST request.

The field can contain only integers or `None` and if the field is `None` it should be substituted with 0.

This is my code:

```
class Validation():
    def __init__(self, param, param_name):
        self.param = param
        self.param_name = param_name
    def check_int(param):
        try:
            int(param)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def check(param, param_name):
        param = param.strip()
        if param == "":
            return 0
        elif Validation.check_int(param):
            return param
        else:
            flash(f"The {param_name} must be an integer!")
            exit()
```

The problem is that if the field contains some string this will trigger the `exit()` function and my program will just stop. I want just to flash the message that this field must be an integer on the screen without executing the POST request in my `views.py` file:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    Validation.check(test1, "Test 1 Parameter")
    Validation.check(test2, "Test 2 Parameter")
    Validation.check(test3, "Test 3 Parameter")
    return render_template('test.html', form = form)
```

[EDIT]: On the web page I have: `test1`, `test2` and `test3` fields and also a submit button. The test fields are defined in the forms.py file as `TextField` and can be either empty or have an integer as a value. If the user puts a float or a string, a message should be flashed on the screen that the input is not valid and the post request should not be executed upon pressing the Submit Button.

Comment: can you tell more what is test1 ,test2 ?

Comment: You're using `exit()` but I think you are wanting to just `return`

Comment: @prashantrana I have added an `[EDIT]` at the end with the additional clarifications.

Comment: @Eqomatic but how to make only if `Validation.check()` is valid to return the `render_template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Validation():

    def check_int(self,param):
        return param.isdigit()

    def check(self, param, param_name):
        param = param.strip()
        if param == "":
            return 0
        elif Validation.check_int(param):
            return param
        else:
            flash(f"The {param_name} must be an integer!")
            return False
```

views.py:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    test1 = Validation.check(test1, "Test 1 Parameter")
    test2 = Validation.check(test2, "Test 2 Parameter")
    test3 = Validation.check(test3, "Test 3 Parameter")
    if test1 is not False and test2 is not False and test3 is not False:
        return render_template('test.html', form = form)
```

Comment: this actually doesn't solve my problem, but then I have added at the `else` statement `return False` and in my views.py before the return I am executing a check if test1, test2 and test3 `is not False`

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov please update my solution to your working solution